# ImageView drag&drop

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I have image what is bigger than actual screen. I have code to drag&drop... everything is working, but the problem when i drag the image, it can go out of screen/view. I would like to make it to corners not go outside... stop when image corners/sides = screen sides... Can somebody help? I would like to make map to my game... If you test the code, you will see what is the problem exactly
Base: i.imgur.com/G4BtCmS.jpg The problem: i.imgur.com/xi9x2nE.jpg And i want to drag stop when image drag = screen corners...all position...left, top, etc...: i.imgur.com/k6I7A7d.jpg But i this code, i can drag out of the screen....: i.imgur.com/xi9x2nE.jpg Can somebody help? How can i make drag&drop boundary? Thank you 
Thank you

Here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="4000dp"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bgtest"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-1000dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-2000dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-500dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.backgroundtest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image;
PointF DownPT = new PointF();
PointF StartPT = new PointF();

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int eid = event.getAction();
            switch (eid)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                    PointF mv = new PointF( event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                    image.setX((int)StartPT.x+mv.x);
                    image.setY((int)StartPT.y+mv.y);
                    StartPT = new PointF( image.getX(), image.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    DownPT.x = event.getX();
                    DownPT.y = event.getY();
                    StartPT = new PointF( image.getX(), image.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To clearly answer your question add the image to your question so someone can easily see it.

And if you just want the image to fit the screen perfectly without moving out of edges. Use constraint layout and added the image view into it and set the height and width to 0dp or match_constratints and use Android:scaletype attribute and set the value to center crop.

Then image will perfectly fit the screen without moving out of screen.

Do let me know if that solved.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no. The background image is bigger than actual screen, and this is ok, because it will be map to my game, like in "Simcity Buildit" or etc... so i want want to move this image... few mins and i will add image...

Comment: if you want the full image to be shown to user then wrap the image inside the scroll view so that the image will be clearly shown.

Comment: The problem: https://i.imgur.com/L8ZTOdJ.png And i want to drag stop when: https://i.imgur.com/L8ZTOdJ.png image go to screen start.... so the background image is bigger than actual screen, and i do not want to match_parent... the problem is i can drag out of the view...

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what are trying to get. Just give me a clear explanation and I'll try my best to solve your issue.

Comment: So, first, thanks for trying help. Next, i have example, 2000dp*3000dp image background, and i would drag&drop it, but if image margins = screen margins, it will stop drag....

Comment: sorry but no, but soon i will add some more images to demonstrate what i want to do exaclty

Comment: Base: https://i.imgur.com/G4BtCmS.jpg
The problem: https://i.imgur.com/xi9x2nE.jpg

And i want to drag stop when image drag = screen corners...all position...left, top, etc...: https://i.imgur.com/k6I7A7d.jpg

But i this code, i can drag out of the screen....: https://i.imgur.com/xi9x2nE.jpg Can somebody help? How can i make drag&drop boundary? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml layout, try to use **LinearLayout** or **ConstraintLayout**.

***If you choose LinearLayout:*** set the ImageView widget's layout_width and layout_height to **match_parent**.

***if you choose ConstarintLayout:*** set the ImageView widget's layout_width and layout_height to **match_constatint(0dp)**.

Comment: The problem: https://i.imgur.com/L8ZTOdJ.png And i want to drag stop when: https://i.imgur.com/L8ZTOdJ.png image go to screen start.... so the background image is bigger than actual screen, and i do not want to match_parent... the problem is i can drag out of the view...